# How do you comment your RTML code?

Tags: rtml

<rant-mode>
Have you ever seen a programming language that does not allow to add comments to the code? Welcome to the world of RTML (may it burn in hell)!
</rant-mode>

### Question

> What is the best technique (if any) you've adopted to comment your RTML code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a comment in RTML, click on your template, then `New`, and in the textbox that says Simple, type (in quotes) your comment.

```
"**************** My comment and stuff ******************"
```

If you want to comment out a piece of code, insert your code after a `MULTI` which groups multiple RTML statements and then a `WHEN nil`. Everything after the `WHEN nil` will never be executed.

```
WHEN nil
    MULTI
        TEXT @a-random-variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at RTML,I wouldn't like working with it directly (it's very ugly).

It seems that the best way would be to have source files, and a preprocessor that strips comments and probably includes shortcuts and new features, then automatically uploads the RTML (maybe even a wasabi for RTML).

You would need to do that in a real language, or go full throttle with something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Comment: Alas, RTML can be edited only online, using ugly Web interface. At least, I am not aware of any other way to maintain it. So I don't see how any extrenal tool could be used. :-(

Comment: An external tool can manipulate the ugly web forms, Something like perl's WWW::Mechanize should be able to easily do that.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT
Inserts a comment into the current page. Equivalent to HTML’s 
construct. A comment is just some text that becomes part of the page’s HTML
source but does not get displayed on the screen. The actual text of the comment
must be a string enclosed in double quotes (or a variable of type text).

Example:

```
 COMMENT "nosearch"
 HEAD
 TITLE "untitled"
 BODY
 TEXT "This
```

please see:  [List of available RTML books and resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464944/list-of-available-rtml-books-and-resources)

Comment: With this approach my code comments (used for "internal purposes") would be exposed to everyone on the resulting page. Sorry, but that is not acceptable. :)